# Apache Spark group sums by field

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the dataframe with three columns

```
amount  type  id
12       A    1
10       C    1
21       B    2
10       A    2
2        B    3
44       B    3
```

I need to sum amounts of each type and group them by `id`. My solution is like

```
GroupedData result = dataFrame.agg(
    when(dataFrame.col("type").like("A%")
            .or(dataFrame.col("type").like("C%")), 
        sum("amount"))
    .otherwise(0)
).agg(
    when(dataFrame.col("type").like("B%"), sum("amount"))
    .otherwise(0)
)
.groupBy(dataFrame.col("id"));
```

which isn't looks right for me. And I need to return `DataFrame` as a result with data

```
amount  type    id
22     A or C   1
21       B      2
10       A      2
46       B      3
```

I cannot use double `groupBy` because two different types may be in one sum. What can you suggest?

I use java and Apache Spark 1.6.2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark dataframes groupby into list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864744/spark-dataframes-groupby-into-list)

Comment: @Aguinore Edge case: what when you have ID = 10 and type = A, B and C? What will be the result?

Comment: A, B and C must be in different rows, so A and C are in one result sum, B in another.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you [groupBy](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#groupBy(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)) by two columns?

```
df.groupBy($"id", $"type").sum()
```

Comment: I wrote the answer in my question. Because some types, like A and C in the example, must be in one sum.

Comment: So you need "A or C" together, but "A" and "B" separate?

Comment: Yes. There are two dozen of types In the real data and I need to calculate sums of different types and its combinations.

Comment: Well I don't think you can do this in one step. You could aggregate by both columns as mentioned above and then do the combinations separately.

Comment: Wouldn't it become a bottleneck, if I will `groupBy` twice?