# Creating nested columns in spark columns with multiple rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create nested column in spark dataframe like this -

```
A | B
a | [1,2, null]
a | [3, null, null]
a | [5,6,7]
```

The printSchema for this dataframe is as follows -

```
|--A: string (nullable = true)
|--B: struct (nullable = true)
|  |--X: long (nullable = true)
|  |--Y: long (nullable = true)
|  |--Z: long (nullable = true)
```

I want the dataframe to be nested like -

```
A | B
a | [[1,2,null],[3,null,null],[5,6,7]]
```

and the printSchema should give same result as before. I've tried to take the first row as an array of fields and concatenate the remaining rows but its not working. 
Can anyone suggest how can I get my desired results ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to create this nested dataframe of yours? reading from a file? If so, are those the contents of your file? Also, the second result can be achieve by `df.groupBy("A").agg(collect_list("B").as("B"))`.

Comment: @philantrovert thats a good solution, Why don't you answer below :)

Comment: @philantrovert , that worked. Thanks !

Comment: It is not possible to change the row content type without changing the Schema (and hence the result of printSchema). If the solution of @philantrovert is correct, then your question is (probably) a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864744/spark-dataframes-groupby-into-list