# Groupby column and create lists for another column values in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a data frame as below:

```
dummy = pd.DataFrame([[1047,2021,0.38],[1056,2021,0.19]],columns=['reco','user','score'])
dummy

reco    user    score
0   1047    2021    0.38
1   1056    2021    0.19
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
user    score   reco
2021    [0.38, 0.19]    [1047, 1056]
```

I want to group by user, and then the lists should be created by score in descending order and the reco should be corresponding to its score values.

I tried collect_list but the order changes. I want to keep the same order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark dataframes groupby into list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864744/spark-dataframes-groupby-into-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preserve ordering by applying `collect_list` over the window function. In this case the window is partitioned by `user` and ordered by `score descending`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

dummy = pd.DataFrame([[1047,2021,0.38],[1056,2021,0.19]],columns=['reco','user','score'])

df = spark.createDataFrame(dummy)

window_spec = W.partitionBy("user").orderBy(F.desc("score"))
ranged_spec = window_spec.rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, W.unboundedFollowing)

df.withColumn("reco", F.collect_list("reco").over(window_spec))\
  .withColumn("score", F.collect_list("score").over(window_spec))\
  .withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(window_spec))\
  .where("rn == 1")\
  .drop("rn").show()
```

### Output

```
+------------+----+------------+
|        reco|user|       score|
+------------+----+------------+
|[1047, 1056]|2021|[0.38, 0.19]|
+------------+----+------------+
```